# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, ubuntu-12.04

Alright So right now I am attempting use the boost C++ libraries in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) as I have previously used them in Windows. So using some example code from the Boost's site

**testfile.cpp**

```
#include <boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    namespace bf = boost::filesystem;
    BOOST_FOREACH(bf::path path,
        boost::make_iterator_range(
            bf::recursive_directory_iterator(bf::path("/home")),
            bf::recursive_directory_iterator())) {
    std::cout << path.string() << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Should very easily compile using this command

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "testfile" -llibboost_filesystem
```

My problem I am getting the linker error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost_filesystem
```

and cannot seem to figure out what I am missing. Please Help.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-lboost_filesystem`?

Comment: Yep your right. I didn't realize that the naming conventions between the files changed there. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost\_filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526546/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-llibboost-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

By convention, library names use the `lib` prefix on most Linux distributions. You should remove this prefix when instructing the linker which libraries to search for. Assuming the gnu `ld` linker, the documentation says

```
-l namespec
--library=namespec

   Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of files to 
   link.  This option may be used any number of times.  If namespec is of the 
   form :filename, ld will search the library path for a file called filename, 
   otherwise it will search the library path for a file called libnamespec.a.
```

so you either want

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "testfile" -lboost_filesystem
```

or

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "testfile" -l :libboost_filesystem.so
```